# Cannot merge node

Tags: neo4j

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
empname          Department    Company

AbdulMarianneB    Marketing     MARG

AdamsCarrollL     Sales         MARG
```

i wanna to import into neo4j using this code

```
LOAD CSV with headers from "file:///C:/Users/Sarah/Desktop/nodes/EmployeeListcsv1.csv" as row
merge (e :empname {name: row.empname})
merge(d :Department {name: row.Department})
merge(c :Company {name: row.Company})
merge (e)-[: works_in]->(c)
merge(d)-[:is_in]->(c);
```

This block above gives me the error:

> Cannot merge node using null property value for name

Answer (score 0):

The format of your CSV-file does not meet the [required specifications](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#csv-file-format):

- the default field terminator is `,`;
- the field terminator character can be change by using the option `FIELDTERMINATOR` available in the LOAD CSV command;

So, you must either modify the source file. Or, for example, explicitly specify the column [separator](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#load-csv-import-data-from-a-csv-file-with-a-custom-field-delimiter):

```
LOAD CSV with headers from 
  "file:///C:/Users/Sarah/Desktop/nodes/EmployeeListcsv1.csv" as row
  FIELDTERMINATOR " "
merge (e :empname {name: row.empname})
merge(d :Department {name: row.Department})
merge(c :Company {name: row.Company})
merge (e)-[: works_in]->(c)
merge(d)-[:is_in]->(c);
```